# View listing page/block relationship configuration

Tags: views, 8

I have a Part-Time Course content type that holds information about whatever course that needs to be added to the site.

I then have a Part-Time Course Offerings content type that has two fields. 
Course Reference, which is an Entity Reference and links it to the Part-Time Course content type mentioned above and Course Offerings, which is an Entity Reference Revisions field type that gets fields from my Part-Time Offering paragraph type. That paragraph type holds various fields including Status and Season.

I have a block view that places the part-time course offerings on each part-time course content type page below the content based on contextual filters of Course Reference based on Content ID from URL.

What I'm now trying to do is create a Course Listing page that lists all the Part-Time Courses that I have but I want to filter it to only show courses that currently have Offerings available. So, if a course doesn't have an Offering available, I don't want it to show up on this listing page. I also want to be able to filter by status and season.

I have a feeling this has to do with Relationships but no matter what combination I've tried, I can't seem to get it to work.

Any suggestions?

The structure is basically like below:

```
Course - Part-Time (Content-Type)

    --> Course - Part-Time Offering (Content-Type)
        - field_course_reference
        - field_course_offerings

          --> Part-Time Offering (Paragraph)
              - various fields including Status & Season
```

**EDIT:** See below answer for an update.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so **Content using field_course_reference** *(Relate each Content with a field_course_reference set to the content.)* was used and required and then **Content using field_course_offerings** *(Relate each Content with a field_course_offerings set to the paragraph.)* was used and required using the first relationship.

This ended up allowing me to filter out and only display courses that had an available offering using Content: Course Reference (field_course_reference) with an operator set to **Is NOT empty**. I was also able to get the other two filters required to work.

However, I still have an issue where instead of just showing the course once, it displays it as many times as course offerings it has. So say that I have 5 different times the course is offered *(The Part-Time Offering [Paragraph] allows for unlimited offering choices)*, it ends up listing the same course 5 times on my page.

Is there any way for the view to only display each course once, disregarding how many offerings are available for each course?

**EDIT:** Found the answer to the above. Once I turned on aggregation in the advanced settings, it only displayed each Course once.